# Each row in DataTable has checkboxes .How to uncheck the previous checked box, on check of new checkbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, selection

On click of Add button, empty row with text box and check box is created. I have to enter the details in text box but only one checkbox should be checked. Now I can check all the check boxes. But if one is checked, other check boxes should be unchecked.

```
<p:commandButton value="Add"
                        actionListener="#{createReturns.addReturnBodyToList}" ajax="true"
                        update="bodyTable messages" style="margin-bottom:10px;"/>
<p:dataTable id="bodyTable" value="#{createReturns.returnBodyList}"
                        var="returnBody">
<p:column headerText="Element Name" style="width:250px;">
                            <p:inputText id="elementName" value="#{returnBody.elementName}"
                                style="width:240px;" />

                        </p:column>
<p:column headerText="KeyColumn" style="width:80px">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{returnBody.keyColumn}" id="key">

                                <p:ajax listener="#{createReturns.toggleCheckBox()}"
                                    event="click" update="key">
                                    <f:attribute name="element" value="#{returnBody.elementName}"></f:attribute>
                                </p:ajax>
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

actionlistener for command button to add empty rows in datatable

```
    public void addReturnBodyToList() {

        returnBody = new ReturnBody();
        returnBodyList.add(returnBody);

    }
```

ajax listener to uncheck other check boxes in bean

```
public void toggleCheckBox(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String elementName = (String) actionEvent.getComponent()
                .getAttributes().get("element");

        for (ReturnBody body : returnBodyList) {
            if (!body.getElementName().equals(elementName))
                body.setKeyColumn(false);
            System.out.println("Check ajax: " + body.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you utilize `<p:column selectionMode="single">`? See also "RadioRutton" example in https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: @JasperdeVries if you have a [selection column](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) (checkbox or radio) the `selectionMode` is secified on that `p:column` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in your toggleCheckBox() method.

```
    boolean flag; //Global
    String lastChecked=new String();//global

    if(!flag){
        setFlag(true);
        lastChecked=elementName;
        }

    if(flag){
     for (ReturnBody body : returnBodyList) {
                if (body.getElementName().equals(lastChecked)){
                    body.setKeyColumn(false);
                    lastChecked=elementName;
                    }
            } 
       }
```